# Memory leak issue with UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, memory-leaks, picker

I'm getting memory leak with UIImagePickerController class.

Here's how I'm using it:

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

To remove the picker i call `[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in `didFinishPickingImage` and `imagePickerControllerDidCancel`.

--

Instruments show around 160bytes leaking as a result of this instruction:

`+[UIImagePickerController _loadPhotoLibraryIfNecessary]`

> Apparently this issue has and is disturbing many people, and solution
>   to avoid this problem is to build a
>   singleton class dedicated for picking
>   images from library or capturing using
>   device's build in camera.
>
> Anyone want to add something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822625/getting-memory-warning-while-using-uiimagepickercontrolleroriginalimage-to-get-i/24830879#24830879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the author of [one of the first articles](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/index.php/2008/11/12/memory-usage-in-uiimagepickercontroller/) about the necessity to use a singleton, the motivation was to prevent a crash on the 7/8th image capture, not because of any particular worry about the leak. 160 bytes is annoying, but not a major problem, and therefore not worth worrying about (because it can't be fixed by developers).

Comment: I'd be interested in whether you still see the crash after 7 or 8 pictures.  I tried reproducing the problem described in your post on 2.2.1 and got no crash after 20 pictures, releasing the picker after each one.  It looks like either the problem's fixed or I'm doing something different than you.

Comment: I haven't tried 2.2.1 yet - I'll give that a go when I get a chance. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I guess i should consider moving to 2.2.1 as well then, if some of the issues will be fixed.

I just found out about this comment feature 10 minutes ago :D. Thanks guys.

Comment: Unfortunately we also need all the users to move to 2.2.1 as well. Until then, we have to keep testing on older versions.

Comment: I just downloaded and ran my application using 2.2.1 and i still see leak in simulator. :( Are you doing anything different? I'm using code in iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf.

Comment: Tom said he gets no crash, not that he gets no leak. The problems aren't  necessarily related - we don't know..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the delegate line? I’ve had similar problems with `AVAudioPlayer` when delegating to `self`. (Even though the accessor says `assign` in both cases.) If the leak goes away with the delegation, you can delegate to a different object.

Answer (score 0):

If you see memory leaks several `GeneralBlock` and `SegmentMachO` by using `UIImagePickerController`,

Try by adding CoreLocation framework and `MapKit` framework to your project. I don't see anymore memory leaks in the instrument tool leak checking. I don't know how `UIImagePickerController` related to these frameworks. I am not sure it is good solution or not. "adding frameworks without using or necessary".

I have also got the memory leak by using `UIImagePickerController`. That memory leak happen even in the sample code "PhotoLocation" and "iPhoneCoreDataRecipes" downloaded from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com). I also checked by adding these frameworks to those downloaded sample code. There is no memory leaks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a memory alloc leak which I found in Instruments.
All I was doing was opening and closing the image picker (open/cancel) and using Apple code, my code and other people's code.

All were showing the allocation going up and up each time, as if the picker was not being released.
If you tried to release it, it would crash (over released).

Then I found a really helpful web page which basically stated:

"This doesn't happen when testing on the device"

So I switched from the simulator and ran the tests on the device.
Lo & behold there was no allocation increase and it behaved normally.

This however is totally evil and now we can place no trust in the simulator to do a reliable job. Whether this is pertinent to your specific problem or not, I took you up on anything else to add, and my thing to add is don't test memory on the simulator!

Answer (score 0):

The reason maybe that you forget to release image. Because each time you write

```
UIImageView.image = image_a;
```

Then , `image_a` will get retained once.

Until you let `UIImageView.image = nil`, when `image_a` can be release finally.

I resolved my problem in this way.