# Getting memory warning while using UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage to get image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, memory-warning

I am using UIImagePickerController for getting image from camera.
Just after I capture image and get it by using UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage getting memory warning.
I am using iphone 4s with iOS.

Code is here

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage* originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

//Getting memory warning after this line
    NSData *data =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 0.1);


}
```

Comment: There's no problem in there. What is it that's bothering you?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061510/memory-warning-uiimagepickercontroller-ios-7

Comment: I am capturing multiple image for making my own image gallery.After few image app is getting crashed

Comment: Run Instruments on your app and check for leaks.

Comment: where you are storing your images.

Comment: In NSArray and after adding in array adding images in scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve these problem with many ways but didn't get success.
Finally I have changed my approach and used AVCaptureSession to take picture from iPhone camera
Here is the sample code provided by Apple

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SquareCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190

All is fine now no memory leaks, performance improved, capturing processes is fast.